# Binding from integer number of days to the WPF UserControl showing both value and unit (Day, Week, Month)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In our WPF application which follows MVVM pattern, there is one property in the ViewModel, which is an integer value representing the number of days. And we would like to present this value in such pattern in WPF: it should contain one `TextBox` and one `ComboBox`, where the text in `TextBox` represents the values of the time and the value in `ComboBox` represents the unit. For example, property value 5 will show as [5][Day], while value 14 shows as [2][Week]. This should be a two-way binding since we want the user to modify it too. Of course such mapping is not one-to-one, 14 can also be represented to [14][Day]. But the principle is the bigger unit has higher priority.

Now weirdly I don't even know what to start with, especially when I want to follow MVVM. Because I only have one value which binds to to destination. And since it is such a simple value, there is no point to create a class as the DataContext of such UserControl

Anyone can give me some hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All this work should be done in `ViewModel`, make the initial integer property private, add two new properties `UnitsCount` and `UnitsType`.

```
private UnitsTypeEnum unitsType = UnitsTypeEnum.Days;
private int unitsCount = 0;

public int UnitsCount
{
    get { return unitsCount; }
    set 
    {
        /* set the number of days based on this new value and UnitsType */
        unitsCount = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UnitsCount");
    }
}   

public UnitsTypeEnum UnitsType
{
    get { return unitsType; }
    set 
    {
        /* set the number of days based on this new value and UnitsCount */
        unitsType = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UnitsType");
    }
}
```

Now make sure in constructor you initialize correctly the `UnitsCount` and `UnitsType` properties for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought about that. I was hesitating because, this kind of property is quite common to many of our Model objects, which means I need to create such code in almost every ViewModel to present the Model data. So I was wondering if there is some way to only define it once (maybe using DataTemplate, Converter, MultiBinding) in Code or XAML?

Comment: This can be done using a `MultiBinding` and a `Converter` as well, but i actually would prefer a separate ViewModel. I will edit my post with an example.

Comment: Could you say a bit more how to do that using MultiBinding and Converter? Or explain a bit more why you prefer the current way? Because like I mentioned, we may have tens of such kind of Model/ViewModel. So I want to avoid copy/paste tens of times

Comment: So you intend to set an Integer value as the `DataContext` of this UserControl and change this value based on some advanced logic using converters/bindings. This logic belongs to a `ViewModel` in my understanding of Separation of concerns. You can create a `ViewModel` instantiated from an Integer value and change your Integer property to a `UnitsViewModel` one, it doesn't look like much work. I tried to come up with an `XAML/Converters` only solution but its not that easy and its ugly too :), but i'm sure it's possible.